Is there a way to say on Altium Designer schematic that a component's pin is not connected?
Is there a way to say on Altium Designer schematic that a component's pin is not connected?

This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).

Yes use the red X, you can find it in the menus at the top of the schematic where you also draw connections etc.

Thank you, on Altium it is called "Generic No ERC", it is represented by a "Red X"
